# Test for trend in r

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, spearman-rho

I have measured a continuous & categorical outcome variables in three groups of patients, where the groups are defined by time periods 2010-2011, 2012-2014, 2015-2016. I would like to test for a "trend" among these three groups--that is, does the continuous/categorical variables increase or decrease across the study periods.

1. What tests should I consider?
2. Is Chi-square trend for categorical and Spearman rank for non-normal continuous suitable?
3. Should I consider Cochran-Armitage for categorical and Mann-Kendall for continuous?
4. Could you recommend an R package that could carry out a suitable analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a test of association for an ordinal variable and a categorical variable, I would be inclined to use Cochran-Armitage.  That's what it's made for.  For a measure of effect size, you might look at Freeman's theta or epsilon squared.

I suppose there are various options for a test of association for an ordinal variable and a continuous variable.  In the example below, I used Kendall correlation.

```
if(!require(coin)){install.packages("coin")}
if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion")}

### Adapted from:
###  http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html
###  http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_11.html
###  http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_10.html

Input =(
"Categorical     A   B   C   D  
Time
2010.2011        15  10  10   5 
2012.2014        10  10  10  10
2015.2016         5  10  10  15
")

Tabla = as.table(read.ftable(textConnection(Input)))

Tabla

library(coin)

Test = chisq_test(Tabla,
                  scores = list("Time" = c(-1, 0, 1)))

Test

spineplot(Tabla)

library(rcompanion)

freemanTheta(Tabla,
             group = "column")

   #### Asymptotic Generalized Pearson Chi-Squared Test

   ### data:  Categorical by Time (2010.2011 < 2012.2014 < 2015.2016)
   ### chi-squared = 10, df = 3, p-value = 0.01857

   ### Freeman.theta 
   ###  0.25 


Input =( 
"Time          Continuous
'2010-2011'     1
'2010-2011'     2
'2010-2011'     3
'2010-2011'     3 
'2010-2011'     4  
'2012-2014'    10
'2012-2014'    10
'2012-2014'    11
'2012-2014'    11
'2012-2014'    12
'2015-2016'   100
'2015-2016'   101
'2015-2016'   102
'2015-2016'   102
'2015-2016'   103
")

Data = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)

Data$Time = as.numeric(factor(Data$Time, ordered=TRUE))

cor.test( ~ Continuous + Time, method="kendall", data=Data)

plot(rank(Continuous) ~ Time, data=Data)

   ###  Kendall's rank correlation tau
   ###  z = 3.9779, p-value = 6.952e-05
   ###  tau = 0.8617275
```